# Правильный удаленный доступ к MySQL

Tags: mysql, vpn, ssh-tunnel

Что есть:

- 1 сервер MySQL в серверной стойке
- Динамическое кол-во клиентов (50-150 компов, некоторые включаются, некоторые выключаются), которые должны работать с этой базой. Клиенты географически распределенные, но имеют стабильный коннект в интернет. Какие-то клиенты работают в режиме 1 запрос в 5-10 секунд, другие генерируют 20-30 запросов в секунду круглосуточно.

Сам вопрос: как организовать коннект клиентов к базе?

Уже рассматривал, но остались вопросы:

- API прослойку *(не подходит из-за слишком большой переделки архитектуры клиентов + доп сервер в стойку)*
- Выставить MySQL "попой" в интернет *(весь интернет пестрит, что это не безопасно, в чем именно не говорят, кроме брутфорса)*
- SSH туннель *(нет личного опыта проверки его на стабильность и реконнекты типа autossh)*
- VPN *(нет личного опыта проверки его на стабильность)*
- *может еще есть что...*

Comment: а есть возможность обеспечить боле менее стабильные IP у клиентов ? Можно было бы выставить его наружу, но закрыть фаерволом.

Comment: неа, динамические айпишник, да еще может и перестановка клиентской машины

Answer (score -1):

Думаю, что единственный правильный вариант - организовать тоннель между клиентами и БД с помощью изолированного VPN канала. Если выбрать стабильный софт и правильно его настроить, все будет работать стабильно. 
API - пушка по воробьям
MySQL наружу - совершенно не безопасно
SSH - костыльно

Хотя, если точно известны IP клиентов, можно выставить MySQL наружу, но дать доступ только нужным адресам.

Comment: IP клиентов будут стоять за натами с динамическими айпишниками. А какой стабильный софт у VPN? В чем именно не безопасность MySQL наружу? И почему SSH костыльно, у меня работает так проект, оч стабильно, только клиентов 4 штуки и кол-во запросов в базу меньше...

Comment: @CyberPulse кулхацкеры постоянно сканируют порты, открытые наружу. Часто находят всякие rdp и mysql даже на альтернативных портах, а потом запускают брутофорс. SSH нужно контролировать, к тому же, это обмен данными по одному протоколу внутри другого. Софт для VPN зависит от используемых ос. Можно даже на роутерах развернуть, а не на серверах.

Comment: ну так у меня на сервере и так открыты ssh, который, судя по логам, брутфорсят не переставая и ничего, еще ни разу не подобрали пароли ни к одному серверу (чуть-чуть ситуацию спасает fail2ban). Как поднять vpn я знаю, просто не знаю как он будет вести себя на множестве мелких соеденений